# Replace NULL values with another column and updating the table

Tags: sql, sql-update

'Can't update the table with the new column.'
'Replacing NULL column from another column'

```
Select a.ParcelID, a.PropertyAddress, b.ParcelID, b.PropertyAddress, (SELECT CASE WHEN a.PropertyAddress IS NULL THEN b.PropertyAddress ELSE a.PropertyAddress END AS column_alias)
    From nashvillehousing a
    JOIN nashvillehousing b
        on a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID
        AND a.UniqueID <> b.UniqueID
    Where a.PropertyAddress is null
    
    Update nashvillehousing
    SET PropertyAddress = (SELECT CASE WHEN a.PropertyAddress IS NULL THEN b.PropertyAddress ELSE a.PropertyAddress END AS column_alias
    From nashvillehousing a
    JOIN nashvillehousing b
        on a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID
    Where a.PropertyAddress is null)
```

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: The way you ask your question, people can only guess what you exactly want. Some more context would be very helpful.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time asking question here. Not really sure how to ask. Basically I'm trying to take the values from the CASE column (column_alias) to be updated into the existing table. When I try to run the first of query, it works but the problem is when I update the table with second set of query and all the null value all turn into one same value which is the first value. Im trying to put a screenshot of it here. Not sure how

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but the scalar subquery seems a bit unusual. If this is SQL Server, have you tried this? For other RDBMS, you will have to check the syntax when doing an `UPDATE` with a self join.

```sql
UPDATE a
SET PropertyAddress = 
    CASE 
        WHEN a.PropertyAddress IS NULL THEN b.PropertyAddress 
        ELSE a.PropertyAddress 
    END 
FROM nashvillehousing a
INNER JOIN nashvillehousing b ON a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID
WHERE a.PropertyAddress IS NULL;
```